# Enabling datalabels plugin makes Y-scales visible on chart | Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I had Y-scales set display to false so they are not visible on the chart. When I enable chart.js datalabels plugin they are forced to display again and I can't prevent them to show up on the chart. Anyone knows what can cause this problem or maybe there is any option in the plugin to hide Y-scales so they are not visible on the chart?

Enabled datalabels plugin seems the way below:

```
plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    options: {
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          align: 'top',
          offset: 5,
          display: 'auto'
        }
      }
    }
```

which is placed in the main config of the chart (place where is type, data or options of chart).
Scales looks that way:

```
scales: {
      y: {
        grid: {
          color: '#333'
        },
        name: 'Temp',
        type: 'linear',
        display: false,
        position: 'left',
      },
      y1: {
        grid: {
          color: '#333'
        },
        name: 'Wilg',
        type: 'linear',
        display: false,
        position: 'right',
      }
}
```

Comment: wrong location for scales options, need to be defined in the options

Comment: be more specific, what do you want to hide? Labels? grid? datas? An image or a snippet can be useful

Comment: I want to hide labels on Y-asix and grid on the chart

Comment: @LeeLenalee sorry, I made a little mistake, it is under options section in main chart config